# Process for publishing a trusted XLL?

Tags: excel, certificate, office-addins, excel-addins, xll

We are developing an XLL Add-in for excel and in order for us to publish it we need it to be trusted by excel,
Is there a way to get our XLL (or code signing certificate) to be inherently trusted by excel? (I'm assuming by getting it signed by microsoft)

Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.